# Calculate antilog in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and android so sorry if I'm asking something fairly obvious.

I need to calculate the Base 10 antilog of a number in Android Studio and am struggling on how to do it. I know it's 10 to the power of x and the only thing I've found in java so far is "y = 10 ^ x;" but this doesn't seem to work if x is non integer ? I've declared x and y as double.

Is there a way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`Math#pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)

```
double y = Math.pow(10, x)
```